# Register Golang gorilla/mux routes in external package

Tags: go, gorilla

In my API I'm going to have a lot of completely separate handlers for each path like "/api/v1/handler_one" and "/api/v1/handler_two". I'm trying to put every handler in it's own package to make it easier to maintain.

I added an example. It's not working since it's not even loading "handlers/handler_one.go". What am I missing?

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "git/myapp/router"
)

func main() {

  myRouter := router.APIRouter

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler: myRouter,
        Addr:    "0.0.0.0:8080",
    }

    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}
```

router/router.go

```
package router

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var Router = mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
var APIRouter = Router.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter()
```

handlers/handler_one.go

```
package handler_one

import (
    "git/myapp/router"
)

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type APIRoutes []Route

var apiRoutes = APIRoutes{
    Route{ "OneIndex", "GET", "/one", OneIndex, },
}

func init() {
    // Register routes
    for _, route := range apiRoutes {
        var handler http.Handler

        handler = route.HandlerFunc
        handler = Logger(handler, route.Name)

        router.APIRouter.
            Methods(route.Method).Path(route.Pattern).Name(route.Name).Handler(handler)
    }
}

// OneIndex is handling the requests to /api/v1/one
func OneIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

  fmt.Println("Doing something...")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's not working since it's not even loading "handlers/handler_one.go"

Do you mean that the `init` function in `handlers/handler_one.go` is not being executed?

That would be expected since in the code you pasted you are not importing that package anywhere.

Try importing that package in your `main.go`.

You can import as `_` if the only reason for importing it would be for the `init` function to run.